# Action filter attribute while opening image url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is like when someone opens url of any files from my asp.net mvc web site I want to track details of that user. Please note I have already added some query string, so only when opens url with that query string I want to track.

For another Action Methods I have already added query string to track via action filter. In action filter I am checking for that query string and if query string is not null and has some value then track that click.

But this logic will not work for direct URLs of files. For more details please see below example URLs.

1. http://wwww.example.com/Home/MyAction?trackerId=123 - TRACKING
2. http://wwww.example.com/Upload/Files/abc.jpg?trackerId=123 - NOT TRACKING

So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could access all requests via the following in `Global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            var trackerId = app.Request.QueryString["trackerId"]
            ...do stuff...
        }
        catch { }
}
```